# Example of non-manifold surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there any example of a surface which is locally homeomorphic to $R^n$ but is not a manifold? (i.e. does not have an well-defiend atlas)

Comment: What's your definition of surface? For that matter, what's your definition of manifold? I'm guessing from the differential geometry tag that you need smooth charts, so a cone (with a sharp point) is probably what you're after.

Comment: Oh I see..maybe I shall restrict that the surface is locally homeomorphic to $R^n$ but can not find an atlas..Is there any such surface?..

Comment: No, because atlases don't need to be finite. But if you say that a surface is locally *homeomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a $2$-manifold is locally *diffeomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^2$, then there are examples (see my first comment).

Comment: The graph of $y(x)=|x|$, the absolute value function would seem to do the job.

Comment: @RyanBudney.I think $y=|x|$ is a manifold..I posted after Mariano's answer, you can have a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example of a topological manifold with no smooth structure is in dimension 4 and is not easy to construct. See for example [Wikipedia's article on the E8 manifold.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold)

Comment: Yeah, I know it. But my purpose is to find a surface satisfies every constraints of manifolds except only an existence of an consistent atlas..

Comment: @hxhxhx88: OK, you didn't specify Hausdorff in your question. In any event, I think I understand what you are asking now, so check out my revised answer.

Comment: Yes I got your point. You are considering topological manifold. Indeed under such circumstance we only need locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. But when we defining differential manifolds, we need the transition map $\phi_\alpha\circ\phi_\beta^{-1}$ to be smooth. They have automatically been continuous, but not necessarily smooth, right? I just want an example to illustrate the necessary of such constraint.

Comment: The first example of a topological manifold with no smooth structure is in dimension $4$ and is not easy to construct. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold

Comment: @hxhxhx88: I forgot to "ping" you on the last comment.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I want, thank you!

Comment: @hxhxhx88: okay, I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no atlas on the cone $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2=z^2, z\geq0\}$ such that the inclusion $i:M\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth inmersion. With its topology induced as a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, there is an homeomorphism $M\cong\mathbb R^2$.

This is one way to formalize your question and to provide an example.
I'll leave the proof as an exercise :-)

On the other hand, one can show that every (second countable, Hausdorff) topological space which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ is (in an essentially unique way, that is, up to diffeomorphism) a smooth manifold. This is a rather different statement. Interestingly, this is not true for manifolds of dimension $\geq4$.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to start by showing the corresponding statement for $M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:y=|x|\}\subseteq\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I think $y=|x|$ is a manifold because we can represent each point by $t$ where $t$ is the distance to the origin and make left side negative. Then the map $t\mapsto t$ is a global chart, right?...

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite curious question: By definition, a (topological) manifold is a topological space that is second-countable and locally homeomorphic to Rn, i.e. every point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to Rn. Hence, an atlas exists by definition (i.e. a collection of charts for every point).

However, as I said, usually one requests a manifold to be second-countable. Hence id you take the disjoint union of uncountably many copies of the unit ball in Rn, you get a topological space that is locally homeomorphic to Rn but that is not second-countable.

Comment: Manifold, in the question, most probably means *smooth manifold*.

Comment: yeah..I mean smooth manifold..